# Valid operation: differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I have:
$$
\begin{cases}
y'(x)^2+y(x)^2=1 \\
     y(0)=0\\y'(0)=1
\end{cases}
$$

This has multiple solutions.

$$
\begin{cases}
x(t)=\sin(t) \\
     x(t)=1\\x(t)=-1
\end{cases}
$$

And want to show that multiple solutions can exist on different intervals, is it valid to show:

$y'(x) = f(y(x)) = \sqrt{1-y(x)^2}$ .

And thus:

$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}$ is not continuous for regions around $(x,1) ,(x,-1)$. So multiple solutions may exist.

Comment: What do you get if you actually solve the DEQ?

Comment: I got sin(x) +C as general solutions, but 1,-1 are a solutions by inspection.

Comment: 1 and -1 do not satisfy the initial conditions.

Comment: sorry my question has been phrased wrong I'll edit it.

Comment: I do not understand your notations. First you use $y$ and $x$, now you use $x$ and $t$. If I understand it correctly, the functions $y(x) = \pm 1$ do not satisfy $y(0) = 0$, so they are not solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that solving the differential equation with $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ is not absolutely required.

From $a^2+b^2=1$ you can deduce $a=\cos(\theta),b=\sin(\theta)$

Similarly here you get $\begin{cases}y'(x)=\cos\theta(x)\\y(x)=\sin\theta(x)\end{cases}$

Actually deriving $y$ gives $\cos(\theta(x))=0$ or $\theta'(x)=1$

The very existence of $y'$ and thus $\theta'$ ensures it is constant on some interval $I$, so a priori the most general solutions are piecewise whose restrictions on the various intervals looks like :

If we consider disjoints intervals $I_n$ and $y_n$ a solution $y/_{I_n}(x)=y_n(x)$ then either

- $\theta_n(x)=\pm\frac{\pi}2\implies y_n(x)=\pm 1$
- or $\theta_n'(x)=1\implies y_n(x)=\sin(\alpha_n+x)$ with $\alpha_n\in\mathbb R$

Assuming that $0\in I_0$ (the index does not matter).

The initial conditions forbid the constant solutions $y_0(x)=\pm 1$

So we have $\alpha_0=0$ and $y_0(x)=\sin(x)$ on $I_0$.

The differential equation is not linear, also it is not in the form $y'(x)=f(y,x)$ but $y'(x)=\pm f(y,x)$ with possible brutal discontinuities, so we have no maximality theorem here.

$I_0$ can be whole $\mathbb R$, but $y$ can also branch to $\pm 1$ when the sinus reaches its maximum or its minimum and stay constant on another interval $I_1$, and branch again to the sinus form on $I_2$ and so on, but at least on the interval that contains $0$ the solution is fixed.

Comment: This makes more sense, would you have any suggested reference or book which deals with existence and in particular this type of existence well?

Comment: maybe this one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_existence_theorem , but I never used it personally, so it is merely a suggestion.

Comment: Had another look over, on your fourth line why does $\theta'(x)^2=1$?

Comment: Derivate $y=\sin(\theta)$ then $y'=\theta'\cos(\theta)=\cos(\theta)$. I reported in $y'^2+y^2=1$ then, but now that you are pointing it out, we can directly say $\theta'=1$. I edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you solved the system without the condition $y'(0) = 1$, I would agree that you can have more than one solution, as $y(x) = \pm \sin x$ would be solutions. Concretely:

$$\bigg(\frac{dy}{dx} \bigg)^2 = 1-y^2(x)$$

which gives

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \pm \sqrt{1-y^2(x)}.$$

Therefore

$$\arcsin x = \int_0^{y(x)} \frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} = \pm \int_0^x dt = \pm x $$
which yields $y(x) = \pm \sin x$.

However, the condition $y'(0) = 1$ forces you to consider $y(x) = \sin x$ as the only possible solution of the initial system.

Answer (score 0):

Take the derivative of your first equation, 
$$
2y'(y''+y)=0
$$
and you see that at any point $x$ at least one of the factors has to be zero. You can switch between the factors when both factors are zero simultaneously.

As the first factor $y'=0$ gives constant solutions and by the original equation $y(x)^2+0^2=1$, this gives the constant solutions $y=\pm 1$.

The second factor gives $y=A\sin(x+\phi)$, $A>0$, and again by the original equation $A=1$. Whenever the sine reaches its maximum, on can thus "rest" at that value $1$ for a while and after that continue with the sine function, the same for the minima at $-1$. Each such piecewise function gives a valid solution for the original problem.

Comment: Why doesn't this break the uniqueness theorem?

Comment: @ocallam : What uniqueness theorem for implicit ODE do you wish to use?

Comment: Picard–Lindelöf theorem , I don't quite understand how the solutions can exist like this.

Comment: For Picard-Lindelöf you need that the differential equation is explicit, and that the partial derivative $\dfrac{∂f}{∂y}$, where it exists, is bounded or $f$ is Lipschitz by other means. In the parts of the domain where that is ensured the solution is unique. However this condition fails at $y=\pm 1$.